# Why does DbContext FirstOrDefault ignore entities that have been added?

Tags: entity-framework-5

I want to search an entityset for objects that I have added to it - but it cant find the object

When I call this proc multiple times with the same entitytypename it always adds a new object.  Why?

```
private EntityRegister  GetEntityRegister(string entityTypeName)
    {
        var er = Db.EntityRegisters.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == entityTypeName);
        if (er == null)
        {
            er = new EntityRegister()

            {
                Name = entityTypeName 

            };
            Db.EntityRegisters.Add(er);


        }
        return er;
    }
```

Comment: Did you save changes? FirstOrDefault goes to the database if you did not save changes the newly added entity is not in the database and therefore FirstOrDefault returns null.

Comment: Thanks Pawel - that's the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you save changes? FirstOrDefault goes to the database if you did not save changes the newly added entity is not in the database and therefore FirstOrDefault returns null.